# C# - iterable data type with type safety and no duplication

Tags: c#

I am trying to find the best way to have a data collection with the following properties:

- Immutable / Read-Only
- Keyed Access rather than string access (ImmutableDictionary will not work, typos will only be exposed at runtime)
- Enumerable (can iterate over)
- Type enforcement of values

Some things I have looked at so far:

plain class:

```
class Foo
{
    public static readonly BarType Item1 = new SubTypeA(Scope: "Global", chickens: 4);
    public static readonly BarType Item2 = new SubTypeB(scope: "Local", chickens: 37);

    public static IEnumerable<BarType> AllItems()
    {
        yield Var1;
        yield Var2;
    }

    public static BarType fetch(int idx)
    {
        return AllItems().ToList()[idx]
    }
}
```

Problem with this approach is that there is a possibility that a dev could by mistake add a new `Item3` but forget to add the explicit `yield` statement to `AllItmes`

Another approach I tried is using reflection:

```
class Foo
{
    public static readonly BarType Item1 = new SubTypeA(Scope: "Global", chickens: 4);
    public static readonly BarType Item2 = new SubTypeB(scope: "Local", chickens: 37);

    public static IEnumerable<BarType> AllItems()
    {
        return typeof(Foo).GetFields().Select(f => (BarType)f.GetValue(typeof(Foo)))
    }

    public static BarType Fetch(int idx)
    {
        return AllItems().ToList()[idx]
    }
}
```

Here the problem is the explicit cast. Adding another field which does not subclass `BarType` will again break at runtime.

I have not found a better solution, and am still using ImmuntableDictionary with string access.

Any suggestions? Speed is not a worry.

---

Answering questions

(1)
Keyed acces is maybe not the best term. Maybe "dot access" is better?

I mean this `Foo["bar"]` -> the compiler cannot validate `"bar"`

Whereas `Foo.bar` will show an error if `bar` is not a field or method on `Foo`

A NamedTuple has this property, but is not iterable.

(2)
ImmutableDictionary does not need string keys. What other keys could I use that would still enforce a 1:1 mapping (each key must match exactly one dictionary value)?

Comment: Why does your immutable dictionary approach have to have string keys? Why does your yield approach not use an array of BarType?

Comment: by 'keyed' do you mean a well know list of values like an enum?

Comment: What do you mean by "Keyed Access rather than string access"? Does your `Foo` class do this? If so, where?

Comment: you can fix the break on the second one by inspecting the type of the fields before casting it or by doing a 'as' cast and testing for null

Comment: `.GetFields().Where(f => f.FieldType==typeof(BarType)).Select(...`

Comment: Can you please answer my question? You've clearly come back here since I posted the comment, but you didn't answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements right, you want to be able to enumerate over all fields of a specific type. I would create the list of fields once:

```
class Foo
{
    public static readonly BarType Item1 = new SubTypeA(Scope: "Global", chickens: 4);
    public static readonly BarType Item2 = new SubTypeB(scope: "Local", chickens: 37);

    private static List<BarType> _bars =
        typeof(Foo).GetFields()
                   .Where(f => f.FieldType==typeof(BarType)
                   .Select(f => (BarType)f.GetValue(typeof(Foo)))
                   .ToList();

    public static IEnumerable<BarType> AllItems()
    {
        return _bars;
    }

    public static BarType Fetch(int idx)
    {
        return _bars[idx];
    }
}
```

Now the only risk is that a developer adds a `BarType` *after* the `_bars` declaration since static members are initialized in the order that they appear in the class. You could mitigate that risk with a stern comment and a unit test that gets all `BarType` fields after initialization and compares it to `AllItems()`.

Comment: does exactly what I want, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
public class SafeDict {

    public enum Keys {
          K1,K2,K3
    }
    private Dictionary<Keys, BarType> _dict = new Dictionary<Keys, BarType>() {
        {Keys.K1, new BarType() },
        {Keys.K2, new BarType() },
    };
    public BarType Get(Keys key) {
        return _dict[key];
    }
    public IEnumerable<BarType> GetAll() {
        return _dict.Values;
    }
}
```

Comment: has same problem as the explicit `yield`: new keys need to be added boot in the dictionary and the enum

Comment: @jisaacstone so what is the criterion for adding new values, I mean its an internal operation since the list of contents is hard coded. You only want to add the new item once? Like a new BarType object